# Arduino PubNub UUID

Tags: arduino, pubnub

I tried setting up an Arduino which publishes some messages to a NodeJaS server, but I cannot get a publisher name out of it. I searched the docs and found nothing really useful. I set an UUID before the PubNub begin with `PubNub.set_uuid(uuid);`, but it had no effect. The application just returns an undefined. How can I set this up?

```cpp
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#define PubNub_BASE_CLIENT WiFiClient
#include <PubNub.h>

// Replace these with your WiFi network settings
const char* ssid = "SSID"; //replace this with your WiFi network name
const char* password = "PW"; //replace this with your WiFi network password

const static char pubkey[] = "KEY";         // your publish key 
const static char subkey[] = "KEY";         // your subscribe key
const static char channel[] = "test"; // channel to use
const static char uuid[] = "temp-sens"; // Unique Device UUID

void setup()
{
  delay(1000);
  Serial.begin(115200);

  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Connecting");
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED)
  {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  PubNub.set_uuid(uuid);
  PubNub.begin(pubkey, subkey);
  Serial.println("PubNub set up");
  Serial.println("success!");
  Serial.print("IP Address is: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
}

void loop() {

   WiFiClient *client;

  char msg[] = "\"Yo!\"";

  client = PubNub.publish(channel, msg);

  if (!client) {
    Serial.println("publishing error");
    delay(1000);
    return;
  }
  if (PubNub.get_last_http_status_code_class() != PubNub::http_scc_success) {
    Serial.print("Got HTTP status code error from PubNub, class: ");
    Serial.print(PubNub.get_last_http_status_code_class(), DEC);
  }
  while (client->available()) {
    Serial.write(client->read());
  }
  client->stop();
  Serial.println("---");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## PubNub Publisher UUID in Received Message

I believe your requirement is to receive the publisher's UUID in the message that is received by the subscriber. This is only possible with latest 4.x versions of the PubNub SDK as they implement a new pub/sub API that provides the publisher's UUID as *additional* [data in the delivered message](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/web-javascript/api-reference-publish-and-subscribe#subscribe-adding-listeners), but not in the actual message content.

For example, if you were to use [PubNub JavaScript SDK](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/web-javascript/pubnub-javascript-sdk), you can get the `publisher` key's value from the message event.

Here is a sample `message event` JSON payload (do not confuse **`message event`** with the `message` key inside of the `message event`):

```json
 {
    "channel": "ch1",
    "subscription": null,
    "actualChannel": null,
    "subscribedChannel": "ch1",
    "timetoken": "15215690220119777",
    "publisher": "cv1",
    "message": {
        "msg": "hello"
    }
 }
```

That `timetoken` is the actual publish timetoken which is made its debut in 4.x PubNub SDKs.

The Arduino SDK is an older SDK and does not implement the newest pub/sub APIs that include this information. As a workaround, you can include the publisher's UUID inside of the message content that you publish.